# how to repeat subscription forever in rxjs and axios

Tags: javascript, rxjs, axios

I'm new to rxjs, I'm following the next [Example](https://itnext.io/working-with-axios-and-rxjs-to-make-simple-ajax-service-module-6fda9ecdaf9f) it uses rxjs and axios to create a simple ajax service. It works just fine, but I wonder, how can i make the subscription repeat the calls forever? i think that maybe javascript setTimeout but.. should be a better way. i read that rxjs have a timer and interval, i tried to implement, but it doesn't seems to be working.

my current code is :

**HTML**

```
<body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.18.0/axios.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.4.0/rxjs.umd.js"></script>
<div>hello world</div><br /><br />
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="input2"></textarea><br />
<button id="theButton2" onclick="performGetRequest2()">click me2</button><br /><br />
<div id="getResult2"></div>
<br /><br />
</body>
```

SCRIPT

```
<script>

    function performGetRequest2() {
        // add prototype method
        //axios.axiosCancel(axios);

        class AxiosSubscriber extends rxjs.Subscriber {
            constructor(observer) {
                super(observer);

                // create sample request id
                //this.requestId = Math.random() + '-xhr-id';
                this.requestId = document.getElementById("input2").value;

                // XHR abort pointer
                this.aborted = false;

                // make axios request on subscription
                axios({
                    url: '../../Home/test2',
                    method: 'get',
                    params: {
                        id: this.requestId
                    }
                })
                    .then((response) => {
                        observer.next(response.data);
                        document.getElementById("getResult2").innerHTML += response.data + "<br>";
                        observer.complete();
                    })
                    .catch((error) => {
                        observer.error(error);
                    });
            }

            unsubscribe() {
                super.unsubscribe();

                // cancel XHR
                if (this.aborted === false) {
                    try {
                        axios.cancel(this.requestId);
                    }
                    catch (ee) {
                        //console.error(ee);
                    }
                    this.aborted = true;
                }
            }
        }

        let observable$ = new rxjs.Observable((observer) => {
            return new AxiosSubscriber(observer);
        });



        rxjs.fromEvent(document.getElementById('input2'), 'input')
            .pipe(
                rxjs.operators.switchMap(() => observable$)
            )
            .subscribe(console.log);
    }


</script>
```

can you please share some of your knowledge ?
you can see a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x9reomhf/) but it wont work since the get request points to a inexistent place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example snippet that will hopefully help you get what you want:

```
import { from, interval } from 'rxjs'; 
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

function axios(url, pollingInterval) {

  // A stub for the axios Promise object. Replace with your real axios Promise object.
  const axiosStub = new Promise((res, rej) => res({ foo: 'bar'}));

  // Convert the axios Promise to an Observable
  const axiosObservable = from(axiosStub);

  // Use the RxJs interval to set up a polling cycle.
  return interval(pollingInterval).pipe(
    switchMap(() => axiosObservable),
  );
}

// Subscribe to axios responses
axios('http://localhost/my/url', 1000).subscribe(res => console.log(res))
```

[StackBlitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-xmfaat?file=index.ts)

Comment: yes! i made the next change and its working fine now!                                  
              rxjs.interval(700)
                  .pipe(
                      rxjs.operators.switchMap(() => observable$)
                  )
                  .subscribe(console.log);

Comment: also this way to be able to unsubscribe from that : subscription = rxjs.interval(700)
                .pipe(
                    rxjs.operators.switchMap(() => observable$)
                )
                .subscribe(console.log);